# Trouble with $PATH on debian

Tags: debian, bash, shell, virtualenv, pip

I think I have a problem with $PATH. I am running a shell script and it is complaining that it doesnt recognize the command even though when I run it manually it does.

**Shell Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# DEPLOYMENT

USR="test"
APP="/srv/www/test"
ENV="/srv/www/test/venv"
LOG="/var/log"

# LOGGING
exec > >(tee -a $LOG/log.log)
exec 2> >(tee -a $LOG/error.log)

# SOFTWARE
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python-dev build-essential nginx python-pip

# PACKAGES
pip install virtualenv uwsgi supervisor

# ENVIRONMENT
mkdir -p $APP
virtualenv $VENV
source $VENV/bin/activate

# FINALIZATION
service supervisor restart
service nginx restart
```

When I run this I get the following error:

**Error Log:**

```
/root/StackScript: line 22: virtualenv: command not found                                             
/root/StackScript: line 23: /bin/activate: No such file or directory                                  
supervisor: unrecognized service
```

When I run the command "pip" manually it says it is installed and recognized. What is happening and how can I diagnose this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you have used VENV without defining it.

> /root/StackScript: line 23: /bin/activate: No such file or directory

the `$VENV` is expanding to nothing so `$VENV/bin/activate` becomes `/bin/activate` and isn't found.

Perhaps you meant

```
VENV="/srv/www/test/venv"
```

at line 6.